# Docker-proxy process is listening on IPv4 and IPv6 but only responding on IPv4

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv6, digital-ocean, forwarding

I'm using Docker Compose to run a DNS server (PowerDNS) within a container. Here is the config:

```
version: "2.4"
networks:
  dnsnet:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts: 
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: "dnsbr0"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - 
          subnet: 192.168.193.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.193.1
  power-dns:
    image: "my_image"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      dnsnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.193.170
    ports:
      - "x.x.x.x:53:53/tcp"
      - "x.x.x.x:53:53/udp"
      - "aaaa::ffff:53:53/tcp"
      - "aaaa::ffff:53:53/udp"
```

From the host machine (running on Ubuntu 18.04 on DigitalOcean), I can `dig @x.x.x.x` and `dig @aaaa::ffff` without issue. From another machine (`bbbb::ffff`) in the same datacenter, I can still `dig @x.x.x.x`, but `dig @aaaa::ffff` times out. I can `ping @aaaa::ffff` no problem—works great, just a 1.5ms round-trip.

The first thing I checked was `lsof`:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -n
docker-pr 7258      root    4u  IPv6  97854      0t0  TCP [aaaa::ffff]:domain (LISTEN)
docker-pr 7272      root    4u  IPv4  97877      0t0  TCP x.x.x.x:domain (LISTEN)
docker-pr 7285      root    4u  IPv4  97919      0t0  UDP x.x.x.x:domain 
docker-pr 7290      root    4u  IPv6  98382      0t0  UDP [aaaa::ffff]:domain
```

That all looks correct. So next I checked a `tcpdump`, first of a `ping`:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n host "aaaa::ffff"
01:24:36.570272 IP6 bbbb::ffff > aaaa::ffff: ICMP6, echo request, seq 0, length 16
01:24:36.570322 IP6 aaaa::ffff > bbbb::ffff: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 0, length 16
01:24:37.574518 IP6 bbbb::ffff > aaaa::ffff: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 16
01:24:37.574558 IP6 aaaa::ffff > bbbb::ffff: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 1, length 16
```

And now of a `dig`:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n host "aaaa::ffff"
00:42:03.291922 IP6 bbbb::ffff.51642 > aaaa::ffff.53: 60840+ [1au] A? example.net. (49)
00:42:08.297904 IP6 bbbb::ffff.51642 > aaaa::ffff.53: 60840+ [1au] A? example.net. (49)
00:42:13.301566 IP6 bbbb::ffff.51642 > aaaa::ffff.53: 60840+ [1au] A? example.net. (49)

$ sudo tcpdump -i dnsbr0 -n host "192.168.193.170"
<nothing>
```

So there doesn't appear to be a reply and, importantly, the `docker-proxy` process never forwards the packets on to the container. Note that a `dig` to the IPv4 address shows up as expected in the dump:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n host "x.x.x.x"
00:46:16.129744 IP y.y.y.y.55183 > x.x.x.x.53: 989+ [1au] A? example.net. (49)
00:46:16.131823 IP x.x.x.x.53 > y.y.y.y.55183: 989*- 1/0/1 A 1.2.3.4 (65)

$ sudo tcpdump -i dnsbr0 -n host "192.168.193.170"
00:46:16.129905 IP y.y.y.y.62620 > 192.168.193.170.53: 16666+ [1au] A? example.net. (49)
00:46:16.131569 IP 192.168.193.170.53 > y.y.y.y.62620: 16666*- 1/0/1 A 1.2.3.4 (65)
```

I also tried doing the ports differently:

```
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
```

This resulted in a different (and expected) `lsof` output but the same behavior and `tcpdump` results.

```
$ sudo lsof -i -n
docker-pr 6982      root    4u  IPv6  95863      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
docker-pr 6995      root    4u  IPv6  95894      0t0  UDP *:domain
```

So what am I missing here? Why is this not working? Have I found a Docker bug?

Comment: Have you tried this locally?

Comment: No, it's not something I can test locally without great difficulty.

Comment: Can it be that if you set an ipv4 address to the network you don't get the ipv6 address exposed?

Comment: No. I tried also setting up a full dual-stack (IPv4 + IPv6) docker network and `ports` still didn't work, with or without static addresses. The only way I was able to get my DNS server to respond to IPv6 queries was to statically assign a publicly-accessible IPv6 address to the container. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I have determined this must be a Docker bug. I have filed a new bug here: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/566

I will accept this as "the" answer if/when the Docker folks agree that I've found a bug.